# .NET IoC: Register type instance created during actual program execution

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm still trying to get to grips with IoC, and I suppose I'm actually on the completely wrong track here concerning the way program flow/type resolution needs to be structured.

I have a WinForms application written pretty much "the old way" which I want to convert to an IoC structure using Autofac for practice purposes.
It consists of a main form from which a logon dialog can be opened, and after successfully connecting to a server, various functions can be performed against the server from the UI using a web service.

I have started configuring the Autofac container by registering the `MainForm` and `LogonDialog` classes, so my code in `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Autofac.IContainer container = buildContainer();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(container.Resolve<Form>());
    }

    private static Autofac.IContainer buildContainer()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MainForm>().As<Form>().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => new LogonDialog());

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        return container;
    }
```

The `MainForm` constructor takes a `Func<LogonDialog>` which is later used to instantiate the logon dialog in a `using` clause. This works.

I am now stuck at the following point:

After successful logon, the `LogonDialog` returns a `Connection` object that holds various information about the connection made to the server. One of its properties is a reference to the web service (`IBackendWebservice`) which is then passed to other objects that implement the various functionalities of the application (vaguely in a ViewModel/Controller manner). So I might have a constructor like `FindRecordController(IBackendWebservice dbservice)`.

The next step in my conversion would probably be wiring up those controller types in the container, and along with those, I would of course like to have the `IBackendWebservice` instance registered so it can be automatically resolved whenever the interface is referenced. The problem now is obviously that at the point when I finally have the `IBackendWebservice` object, the container has already been built and can't accept any new registrations (and I don't have a reference to it anyway in my `MainForm`).

One thing that came to my mind right now is that I probably have to wire up a factory delegate for the `Connection` class and pass it to the `LogonDialog`, so the container has a reference to the `Connection` object I'm working with. But how would I then have to register the `IBackendWebservice` interface as a property of that `Connection` instance ? And how would I make sure the `Connection` instance can and will be replaced when a new connection is made through the logon dialog, but not in any other place the `Connection` type is being resolved ?
Does this thought make any sense at all ?

Thanks for any *pointers.

Comment: actually you can update a container by creating new ContainerBuilder and executing Update method with container as paramerar like:  builder.Update(container)

Comment: Thanks; I didn't know you can modify a container after building it. But after reading some more - that would mean making changes to the registration outside the composition root, and from what I understand, that should be the only place where types are registered, right ? [Yes, I know my question was actually pretty much asking for that. ;-)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can communicate your intent through your design by letting `LogonDialog` take a dependency on a `ConnectionContainer`, which has a `Connection` property.  Only types that may set the connection will take a dependency on it.  Other types will take a dependency on `Connection` as they always did, but you can resolve it directly from the container:

```
builder.RegiserType<ConnectionContainer>();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ConnectionContainer>().Connection).AsSelf();
```

(with scpoing modified as needed).